# Quick Way to Mass Downgrade Packages in Android Studio Flutter Project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

So this question is somewhat of an offshoot of this one here: [How to downgrade packages in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214312/how-to-downgrade-packages-in-flutter)

Sure, I could go through each package version, specify what each older package is, and keep building it until it doesn't throw any warnings/errors.

However, I was wondering if I could specify Android 30 SDK somewhere, and have it auto-configure the packages to meet that SDK target?

I know in my `build.gradle` I can specify a target Android sdk:

```
android {
    compileSdk "30"

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdk "30"
    }
}
```

However I'm wondering if in my YAML or Android Studio if I could do something like `ALL_PACKAGES:TARGET: "30"`
Oh, or perhaps run some sort of cmd line in my flutter project directory?

I've been getting into Flutter Android development for a few months now, and I haven't seen anyone mention any sort of feature like that, so I figured I would ask.

I'll be sure to update if I personally find anything.

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems there may not be easy solution to perform anything that you mention. Please take a look at this: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-downgrade