# error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, gradle, kernel, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am getting this error Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
this error have come suddenly, I dont no why.
How to fixed it

```
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart:234:9: Error: Type 'ui.ViewConfiguration' not found.
  final ui.ViewConfiguration configuration;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart:241:3: Error: Type 'ui.ViewConfiguration' not found.
  ui.ViewConfiguration get viewConfiguration => configuration;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart:174:27: Error: Method not found: 'ViewConfiguration'.
        configuration: ui.ViewConfiguration(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart:232:3: Error: The superclass, 'ui.FlutterView', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  _FlutterView({required this.configuration});
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart:234:12: Error: 'ViewConfiguration' isn't a type.
  final ui.ViewConfiguration configuration;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.9.3/lib/src/fonts/font.dart:47:15: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:printing/src/fonts/manifest.dart'.
    if (await AssetManifest.contains(asset)) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/file_version_info.dart:13:17: Error: Field 'wLanguage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? wLanguage;
                ^
/C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/file_version_info.dart:16:17: Error: Field 'wCodePage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? wCodePage;
                ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1153

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

### this is my app/buld.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.bellaz"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

### this is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### this is my pubspex.ymal file

```
version: 1.0.0+2

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  pin_code_fields: ^7.3.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
#  dropdown_formfield: ^0.1.3
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
#  dart_notification_center: ^1.0.0+1
  maps_launcher: ^2.0.1
  share_plus: ^4.0.8
  http: ^0.13.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  skeletons: ^0.0.3
  geolocator: ^7.4.0
  flutter_geocoder: ^0.2.2-nullsafety
  cool_dropdown: ^1.4.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.3+2
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.26
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.0
  location: ^4.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  map_picker: ^0.0.3
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  pdf: ^3.7.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  open_filex: ^4.3.2
  printing: ^5.9.3
  provider: ^6.0.5


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "lib/Assets/app_icon.png"
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your targetSdkVersion to 30 and minSdkVersion to 21 in your app level build.gradle file

```
 minSdkVersion 21
 targetSdkVersion 33
```

to

```
minSdkVersion 20
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Comment: No I cant changed  my my plugins are depended on sdk 33

Answer (score 0):

The **issue** is with `printing` and `package_info_plus_windows`. They are imported in your code.

- There should be missing some classes and constructors.

---

[**Upgrade**](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/upgrading) or [**downgrade**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214312/how-to-downgrade-packages-in-flutter) the `packages`.

Update the `printing` and `package_info_plus_windows` packages with this command.

```
flutter packages upgrade
```

If it's not working follow this [How to downgrade packages in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214312/how-to-downgrade-packages-in-flutter).

```
flutter packages get
```

---

[**Clean**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279379/how-to-clear-flutters-build-cache) your project with the commands:

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter run
```

---

[**Invalidate caches and restart**](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/193/how-to-clear-flutter-project-build-cache/).

---

I would also check the Flutter SDK and for imports. They can create conflicts between the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a new version of printing 5.10.4 works fine with SDK version 33. Just need to upgrade the printing package version.

Answer (score 0):

In my can this is only due to share_plus package, initially I was using the share_plus: ^6.3.1, but after using latest version that is share_plus: ^7.0.2 it was working fine for me. So, you can try to use latest version of share_plus package.