# Old flutter apps are not working on Flutter 3.10.2... errors in build

Tags: flutter

Really I am in a trouble I have notification from google play to rectify some permissions for a three Apps but I was trying for weeks to run these Apps after I updated to flutter 3.10.2, and I am using Android studio chipmunk... the error & cam getting when running to android is

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/file_version_info.dart:13:17: Error: Field 'wLanguage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? wLanguage;
                ^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/file_version_info.dart:16:17: Error: Field 'wCodePage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? wCodePage;
                ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/macbook/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/macbook/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and here are my dependence from `pub spec.Yaml`

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  fl_chart: ^0.50.1
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.3.1
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.1.6
  rate_my_app: ^1.1.2
  upgrader: ^4.4.0
  pdf: ^3.8.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  share_plus: ^4.0.7
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^20.2.38-beta
  screenshot: ^2.1.0
```

I tried for weeks & no result, can anybody help me ....also in IOS the app is not building as well.

Comment: Consider applying suggestions from this answer to see if they help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75792267/7034621